# How to set permissions when uploading to Amazon S3?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to set permissions for the files I'm uploading to S3 to be "Read" for All users, but can't find the way to use `AWSS3PutObjectRequest grantRead` neither `AWSS3Permission AWSS3PermissionRead`.

Any suggestion how to solve the problem?

Here's my code:

```
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest.body = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
uploadRequest.key = fileName
uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
uploadRequest.grantFullControl = "All users" // I think here's an error
self.upload(uploadRequest)
```

When I comment out the line `uploadRequest.grantFullControl = "All users"` the file gets uploaded, but the privilege for All users is set to None. I think the problem is in the penultimate line in the above code. When the line is not commented out I get this error:

*upload() failed: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 0.)" UserInfo=0x191a5bc0 {HostId=xxx+xxxxxxx/14=, ArgumentValue=All users, Message=Argument format not recognized, ArgumentName=x-amz-grant-full-control, Code=InvalidArgument, RequestId=xxxx}]*

**EDIT**: The code above actually tries to grant full control permissions but the core problem is the same. Also I've added an image showing privileges for uploaded file:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest.body = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
uploadRequest.key = fileName
uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.PublicRead  // there was the error
self.upload(uploadRequest)
```

More details at: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=109840
[image]